# Cancel iPhone and iPad apps availability on Mac App Store after Big Sur starts

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ipad, macos-big-sur

From Big Sur, macOS 11, all iOS(iPhone/iPad) apps can be used on Mac.

In this web page https://developer.apple.com/support/ios-ipados-mac, Apple says:

> If you prefer not to have your app published on the Mac App Store, you
> can manage its availability in App Store Connect at any time.

Does **"at any time"** mean you can cancel your app availability on mac after Big Sur starts?

Or you can manage availability **any time, only before Big Sur starts**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manage availability right now. Mac availability doesn't have anything to do with Big Sur. If you turn it on, users will start seeing your app in Mac App Store. If you turn if off, they won't.

Also turning this option off won't affect existing downloads. Those users can continue using app.

Option is available under Pricing & Availability on AppStoreConnect. Changes to Mac store availability (Yes/No) would be similar to changing any other availability options.

From ASC Help: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev2de8e790b

> If your iOS app offers universal purchase and has an existing macOS platform, the option to offer the iOS app on the Mac App Store will not be available

> You need to be Account Holder, Admin, or App Manager to change availability.

Your App -> [https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/apps/${APP_ID}/appstore/pricing](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/apps/$%7BAPP_ID%7D/appstore/pricing)

AppStore Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I know I can manage availability right now. I want know whether I can manage availability after Big Sur starts. If I set availability to No right now, can I change it to Yes after Big Sur? And, if I set availability to Yes right now, can I change it to No after Big Sur?

Comment: For example, you can manage iPad availability for iPhone app any time, at any point, but you will never able to change it to No from Yes.

Comment: Updated my answer. It is not one time option. You can change it anytime. Think of availability as, is it available to download NOW?.

Comment: Thanks! I'm relieved to hear that. I thought this option might be a trap.